# Transition fuctions only depend on homotopy

Tags: differential-geometry, instantons

In the [nLab article about Instantons](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Yang-Mills+instanton) in the section about the clutching construction, it is stated that one can construct $SU(2)$-bundles over $S^4$ via Chech cohomology choosing appropriate transition functions $g_{ij}:U_i\cap U_j \rightarrow SU(2)$ for an appropriate covering $\{U_i\}$ of $S^4$. In the article it is chosen the covering given by two open sets $U_+:=S^4\setminus${point at infinity}  and $U_-:= ${tiny neighbourhood of the point at infinity}. Later in the article it is stated than "one finds that instantons are classified by homotopy classes of maps $g:S^3\rightarrow SU(2)$" but I can't understand why. Somehow only the information about the homotopy of the intersection of the two open sets is enough. Can anybody help me?